# Determining the elements in a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Say $G$ is a group with exactly six elements $\{a,b,c,d,e,f\}$.
Further, the following is defined: $a^2=b^2=d^2=d$, $e^2=f$, $ab=e$.

I have to determine the following elements in $G$.

1. $bc$
2. $ac$
3. $f^{-1}$
4. $df$

I assume that $d$ is the neutral element in $G$, since $d^2=d$. So far I have the following.

1. $bc=bc$
2. $ac=ac$

Is this correct? And how can I determine the elements of $f^{-1}$ and $df=$?
For $f^{-1}$, do I have to find the inverse of $f$ such that $ff^{-1}=d$? Some hints about how to proceed would be enough. Thank you in advance!

Comment: If $d^2=d$ then $d$ is the identity.  Usually people use $e$ for the identity element...Also, you have no relations at all involving $c$....

Comment: I modified my question with your feedback

Comment: You still have no relations involving $c$ so $c$ has infinite order?

Comment: What does the comma in $b,c$ mean?

Comment: My text book doesn't show any relation involving $c$

Comment: @BabakS. How is $a^{-1}ec = aec$?

Comment: @lulu: $c$ can not be infinite order if the group has order $6$.

Comment: @fuglede Sorry, it was a typo

Comment: So I guess $c=c$?

Comment: And $df=f$, since $d$ is the neutral element?

Comment: Well, $bc = bc$ is obviously true, but probably does not count as that element being "determined", from the viewpoint of who designed the exercise.

Answer (score 3):

> Any group of order $6$ is either isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_6$ or $S_3$.

The group here is $S_3$ ( clear from the operations between the elements given here)where the elements are

$a=(12),b=(23),c=(13),e=(123),f=(132)$ and $d$ is the identity

Now just compute the expressions

Comment: This is not a homomorphism, as the product of the images of $a$ and $b$ is not the image of $e$.

Comment: I don't know what you are telling $(12)(23)=(123)$ ;So what's the problem@fuglede

Comment: Why the downvote?@fuglede;Your technique is exactly the same as that of mine

Comment: Well, fair enough, it depends on whether you act from the left or the right. There is a small amount of discussion on what is more common on https://mathoverflow.net/questions/151258/how-do-most-people-write-permutations

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way to solve this without making an explicit isomorphism to $\mathcal{S}_3$:

First consider the order of each element. You deduced correctly that $d$ is the neutral element, hence $\text{ord}(d) = 1$. This also means that $\text{ord}(a) = \text{ord}(b) =2$.

Now, we know that $e^2 = f \neq d$. Because the group has order $6$, we know that $d = e^6 = f^3$, so $\text{ord}(f) = 3$. And we also know that $e$ does not have order $1$ or $2$, so it must have order $3$ or $6$.

If $e$ were to have order $6$, then our group would be cyclic. However, in that case, $e$ would have order $6$, $e^2$ order $3$, $e^3$ order $2$, $e^4$ order $3$ and $e^5$ order $6$. However, we have two distinct elements of order $2$, so this cannot be. Hence $\text{ord}(e) = 3$.

Note that we also know now that $f^{-1} = f^2 = e^4 = e$, meaning that $e$ and $f$ are inverses!

Now consider $c$, which must have order $2$ or $3$. If $c$ were to have order $3$, then its inverse $c^{-1}$ also has order $3$. So $c^{-1}$ must be either $e$ or $f$. But if $c^{-1} = e$, then $c = f$; and if $c^{-1} = f$, then $c = e$. Both lead to a contradiction, so $\text{ord}(c) = 2$.

Now, let's go through your cases.

1. $bc$. This is the only hard part, really. Suppose first that $bc = a$, then $abc = a^2$, but since $a$ has order $2$ and $ab = e$ we then find $ec = d$. But $e$ and $c$ are not inverses, so $bc \neq a$. Next, we try $bc = f$. Then $bc = e^{-1} = (ab)^{-1} = ba$, and then $c = a$, contradiction. So $bc = e$.
2. $ac$. Use that $ac = a(b^2)c = (ab)(bc)$.
3. $f^{-1}$. We already determined this in the previous steps somewhere.
4. $df$. Use that $d$ is the neutral element.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comprehensive answer. Just to know that I understood your explanation: Is $ea=f$ and $eb=ab=e$ correct?

Comment: My solutions are as follows: $bc=e,df=f,ac=f,ea=f,f^{-1}=e,eb=e$

Comment: Your solutions for $bc$, $df$, $ac$ and $f^{-1}$ are correct. However, $ea \neq f$ and definitely $eb \neq e$: multiplying both sides by $e^{-1}$ would then give that $b = d$.

For $ea$, you could use that $ac = f = e^{-1}$, hence $e = ca$. Thus $ea = caa = c$. For $eb$, use that $e = ab$ hence $eb = abb = a$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $G$ has order six, we know that $G$ is isomorphic to either $\mathbb Z_6$, $\mathbb Z_3 \times \mathbb Z _2$, or $S_3$. As noted in the comments above, $d$ is the trivial element, so $a$ and $b$ have order $2$. Thus, $G$ must be isomorphic to $S_3$, so we are good to go, if we can find that isomorphism, $\phi$. Assume that it maps $a$ to $(1 2)$ and $b$ to $(1 3)$. It follows that $\phi(e) = \phi(ab) = (1 2 3)$, and $\phi(f) = \phi(e^2) = (1 3 2)$. Finally, as we have excluded all other possibilities, this implies that $\phi(c) = (2 3)$, the only remaining non-trivial element. Note now that $\phi$ is actually a well-defined bijective homomorphism and thus one of the possible isomorphisms to $S_3$.

Now, for instance, $\phi(bc) = (1 2 3) = \phi(e)$, so $bc = e$.

Comment: Could you please explain "so a and b have order 2"? How do you conclude this?

Comment: @Javiator: They square to the trivial element, so this is simply the definition of order of an element of a group.